# Need advice for a sci-fi Scylla and Charybdis

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-travel

I want to set up a "Scylla and Charybdis" pair of hazards to space navigation. My idea is to have them blocking the end of a galactic arm that needs to be reached. I had a few ideas for both, but am looking for added ideas for:

Charybdis: I mostly have figured out, as a singularity makes perfect sense. My one question for Charybdis is: are there black holes that erratically/periodically vary the radius of their event horizon? While I want the two bodies to be just beyond each other's influence, I think it would be cool (especially if Scylla is at least partially a nebula of some sort) for Charybdis to periodically "grab hold" of little pieces of Scylla, drawing tendrils of her across their border and into Charybdis' accretion disk.

Scylla: I'm not quite sure what I want Scylla to be. Ideas include a pulsar of incredibly devastating power, or some manner of acidic/energy-devouring/sensor jamming nebula that perhaps also houses an asteroid field/ship graveyard, or perhaps an anomalous field of space prone to temporary wormholes opening without warning, or perhaps a single large wormhole whose far opening is unstable and periodically brushes the event horizon of a larger (like galactic core size) black hole, suddenly creating several tendrils of incredibly intense gravitational pull into the hole.

So my questions boil down to:

1. is a varying-diameter singularity a plausible anomally for space travellers to encounter and
2. I listed concepts for Scylla, but do not pretend to be an astrophysicist, so would like to know if there are other interesting phenomena out there that did not occur to me. And
3. if one or more of my Scylla ideas would be irrational/immersion-breaking in a semi-science based sci-fi setting, I'd like any red flags pointed out

Comment: Sorry, we don't provide ideas nor preferences. We solve measurable problems.

Comment: Space is big. Really, really, really big. There is no reason whatsoever for anybody to plot a course through a dangerous strait, when they can go *around* it. (And varying the radius of the event horizon is the same thing as varying the mass of the black hole... Which is quite problematic.)

Comment: Hi HA, welcome to Worldbuilding! As L.Dutch points out, this currently sounds like a brainstorming and opinion-based question, which makes it hard to answer definitively and objectively. I've voted to place your question on hold until you get a chance to narrow the topic down a bit, so you don't get a bunch of unhelpful answers.

Comment: @AlexP you can constrain the issue though, if the way around involves centuries of sublight travel and the route past the contrived obstacles is the FTL shortcut/jump-point/wormhole mouth/whatever. Impatience always wins.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: Right. So mankind has the ability to travel quickly to the depths of deep space where wormholes and erratic black holes live, but somehow they cannot go around said obstacles... Say the area affected by the dastardly phenomena is 1000 light years across; but then is also quite obviously many thousands of light years away. How much longer is the course which goes around the area than the course which goes straight through? Compute the result as a percentage.

Comment: @AlexP are you genuinely unable to imagine a transport system that does not allow you to go everywhere with equal ease?

Comment: @AlexP in case the answer is "yes", consider a wormhole network in which a second has become almost entirely disconnected, and the remaining mouth is is inconveniently close proximity to something that is dangerous and yet not 1000ly across (eg, some idiot set up next to a neutron star, or turned its primary into one). Imagine that the wormhole network wasn't built by humans, but is being explored by them. Imagine an FTL system that does not work in a 1000ly radius but for one specific route, and the thing of interest is at the middle. See how easy this is?

Comment: Fair enough on the input/brainstorming.  My key problems are: 1) is a varying-diameter singularity a plausible anomally for space travellers to encounter and 2) I listed concepts for Scylla, but do not pretend to be an astrophysicist, so would like to know if there are other interesting phenomena out there that did not occur to me. And 3) if one or more of my Scylla ideas would be irrational/immersion-breaking in a semi-science based sci-fi setting, I'd like any red flags pointed out.

Comment: As for the "go around" humans have FTL (two types, the mothership has a barely faster than light "slip drive" that is slow as sin by ftl standards, but only consumes fuel when first accellerating/slipping into subspace and when dropping out of ftl, allowing it to crawl along for centuries with passengees in stasis and ai at the helm and "jump drives" that travel much faster than light but consume large ammounts of fuel/energy based on distance.) however, they are not capable of skipping over obstacles also (cont'd)

Comment: Scylla is tricky: choosing Scylla means accepting that some must die for the good of the mission.  Ever since I heard that story there has been a part of my brain scheming ways to get by Scylla without having her take her meals.  I have to think on a space ship, you would send robots or drones or some nonsentients to run interference, which defeats the whole point of Scylla.

Comment: @HAHarvey if you can condense that down into a few bullet points, it might be reasonably editted into the question as those things seem relevant.

Comment: Also, the idea of it being on an outer arm of the galaxy is that "going around" would leave the influence of the galaxy, which is both spinning and moving through space.  Human craft are not capable of "catching" the galaxy once they break free. The need to go through instead of around is also because the human fleet is incapable of defeating the enemy fleets head-on and must bypass them to attack the homeworld: a sort of "quiet feet creaping into mordor" tactic.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the brainstorming and specify more what I meant to ask for.

Comment: @StarfishPrime edited in the bullet points, though the system turned them into a paragraph

Comment: @Willk exactly the dilemma I had in picking a Scylla. The closest (you will lose some goung this way) were the rabdom wormhole field and the wormhole with moving, invisible, black-hole gravity tentacles. As a fleet would be moving through, some could make it, but not all.

Comment: @HAHarvey for bullet points use 1. instead of 1) to get automagic formatting.

Comment: @HA Harvey 1) A galactic arm is not exactly a real thing. The bright young stars and other bright objects in a spiral arm make it look brighter when seen from outside.  But there are just as many ordinary typical stars and planets per cubic light year outside a spiral arm as inside it.  Therefore travelling along a spiral arm is not necessary.  2) Even if they are restricted for some strange reason to traveling along a spiral arm, The width of the spiral arm would be about 1,000 light years, so it should be easy to go between or around them.  Continued.

Comment: @HA Harvey 3) one danger of black holes is that within the event horizons their escape velocities are greater than light, so not even light can escape from them.  But if your characters are making such a long journey as implied, their ships should travel hundreds and thousands of times as fast as light and could escape from inside the event horizon.  4) tidal forces near a black hole can disrupt objects both outside and inside the event horizon.  But the larger the area affected by the black hole's gravity, the gravity gradients will be less steep and the tidal effects less dangerous.

Comment: @M. A. Golding I like your points. 1) good to know, but the badguy's defense blockade will still work for making S&C the only viable entry point. 2) Badguys defending their space except for one path behind enemy lines still works. 3) Very cool. Makes that path have an added complication of trying to take a fleet through with ebough ftl fuel to burn hard through the event horizon . . . and account for time dilation while doing so (but that's another question) 4) yep, I was figuring Scylla woulf extend pretty much across one side of Charibdis' accretion disk. Just used EH as the msr of total inf

Comment: I'll start a new question on the time dilation since this has been put on hold even though though I made the edits that were requested.

Answer (score 4):

## Grey Goo

Scylla is a disc of grey goo, multiple thousands of light years in diameter.  It is the remnant of an ancient civilization, technology far more advanced than your characters possess.  They can't disable it, they can't destroy it.  Maybe it was created by a race that lived on your targeted spiral arm for defense.  Or by their enemies as a cage.

Though it stays in the position it was programmed to, if anything comes within a few dozen light years of it Scylla spreads out, catches it, and consumes.  Adds it to the collective.  Maybe it can even assimilate the technology, if it is useful.

Charybdis is not just the danger of the straights, it is also the source.  The black hole consumes the grey goo, and there in nothing Scylla can do about it.  But it also messes with the nanites' sensor web.

To get through, a ship has to navigate close enough to the singularity, that the nanites cannot detect it.  Without getting so close that they get trapped in the gravity well.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that!

Answer (score 4):

I'm calling a bit of a frame challenge with this answer. The point of Scylla and Charybdis was to create an ethical dilemma for Odysseus - the original 'rock and a hard place'. Scylla would lead to the definitive deaths of a few crew members. Charybdis, on the other hand, may lead to the deaths of everyone, or the deaths of no one. It's an interesting quandary to be sure.

So here we have a pair of space obstacles, with behave in this manner. One *may* kill everyone, one *will* kill a few of them. Your solution isn't going to be blocking them, because of just how mind-numbing large space is, insert H2G2 quote here. Instead, make it on space travel.

Space is big, which makes travel necessitate various methods and concepts, like hyperspace, FTL, ramships, colony ships, etc. etc. So give your protagonists two choices of space travel - one which risks a few crew members, and the other risks the ship. Say the traditional method of hyperspace jumping randomly generates super gravity fields around the ship and kills any crew member in it, and there's a new experimental one which either doesn't generate it at all, or generates one across the entire ship (they're still working out the bugs). I believe Warhammer 40K is [particularly instructive](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Warp-Drive) if you seek more examples, though note that their hyperspace is inhabited by demons.

Comment: I like that application, for a different story/setting. In the current setting I am working on, the ftl drives the humans have work, but don't skip over physical barriers. The idea behind the blocking here is there is an enemy alien force that is winning a war of extinction on the other races in the region. Borders into badguy space is well-guarded with the exception of these paired anomallies (which the humans nickname scylla and charybdis because of obvious similarities) which they cannot imagine someone bypassing. It is as much a LotR inspired scenario as it is Oddessy inspired.

Comment: Your first problem is that space can't be blockaded by physical barriers. There's just not enough physical matter to do it. That said, take a look at binary black holes.

Comment: No, but ships with limited ftl range before refueling can be blockaded from travelling deeper into a protected area of space, unless someone could build and protect a deep-space refueling station that itself could operate without fuel or solar energy. IOW, the only "in-range" systems are guarded by superior forces with greater ftl range and detection. Thus, their sector of space IS blockaded successfully.

Comment: Another variant of the same dilemma: You have two ships near a star about to go supernova, and your only chance to evade are two wormholes you could use to escape. You know that only one of the wormholes is stable, allowing you pass through, while the other one is unstable and will collapse when trying to pass through. The problem is: You don't know and can't figure out which of the wormholes is the stable one. Your dilemma now is: If you fly both ships through the same wormhole, you have a 50% chance to destroy both ships. But sending a ship through each means sure destruction of one of them.

Comment: @HAHarvey There shouldn't be fuel restrictions because there's no resistance in space so you don't run into the problems you do for just adding more fuel tanks on Earth. Also, a deep space refueling station that goes completely dark should be impossible to detect, especially considering that any emission is limited by the speed of light.

Comment: Fuel restrictions: the "warp buble" that allows ftl travel requires tremendous amounts of energy to maintain. Boom. The ships in the game also have a "maximum speed" in sublight that is actually maximum safe maneuvering speed, as any time they spend accellerating, they also need to spend decelerating.

Comment: The detection thing is assuming that the badguys don't have ftl-capable detection. Again, when dealing with an enemy with superior technology by several steps, one can argue all one wants that it's impossible to locate a stealth base, but the fact that they keep finding them and destroying them makes one look like a fool after a while.

Comment: @HAHarvey If you want to set the rules like that, go ahead. It's your world. But you'll only restrict yourself if you never want to look back at the rules you set in place and adjust them to help the story.

Answer (score 1):

> My one question for Charybdis is: are there black holes that erratically/periodically vary the radius of their event horizon?

The radius of a black hole is determined by its mass, angular momentum and charge. Since neither of those can vary erratically due to conservation laws, nor can the radius of a black hole's event horizon. The only way those can change is through interaction with surrounding matter that falls into it.

Moreover, there is the second law of black-hole dynamics: The area of a classical black hole's event horizon can only ever grow, never shrink (the similarity to the second law of thermodynamics is no accident; indeed, according to current theories, event horizon area and black hole entropy are linked).

When taking in account quantum mechanics, black holes *can* shrink through Hawking radiation. But this isn't erratic, but a steady radiation. Moreover, it is the weaker the more massive a black hole is; for a stellar black hole, the amount of mass it accumulates due to cosmic background radiation falling in is larger than the mass it loses due to Hawking radiation. And even if we would put those black holes into a completely empty universe, they would shrink so slowly that even at the age of the universe, the change would be negligible.

A hypothetical smaller black hole would radiate more, and therefore shrink considerably; however that shrinkage would not be erratic either, but accelerating until eventually the black hole ends in a big explosion.

So in summary, a stellar black hole will only grow, and that growth is not erratic, but depends entirely on what falls into the black hole. A hypothetical small black hole would radiate and shrink, but not erratically either.

Comment: Science admittes black holes shrinking by giving out Hawkings radiation, in a process called black hole evaporation. Even so the large ones would take longer than the age of the universe to shrink by a considerable amount.

Comment: @Renan: Good point, I forgot about that. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @celtschk thanks! That's one of the questions I wanted answered, even if that answer was "no, don't be silly"! Renan that's cool, not useful for charybdis but still cool. Are the gamma bursts black holes emit the same/related thing as what you are talking about, or something different?

Comment: @HAHarvey: The gamma ray bursts are something different. Those gamma rays don't actually come from the black hole itself, but from matter that falls into the black hole.